# Add Post Tags to Body Class

Tags: posts, tags, post-class

Want to add post tag name to body class - I am successful in using the code below to add category to body class -

```
 //adds new body class for post category
add_filter('body_class', 'add_category_class_single');
function add_category_class_single($classes){
     global $post;

    $category = get_the_category($post->ID);
    $slug = $category[0]->slug;
    $classes[] = 'post-category-' . $slug;

    return $classes;
 }
```

however when i try to use get_the_tags i am not having any luck - any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

That is because the `get_the_tags()` function returns an array with the tag id as the key value. You could use `array_values( get_the_tags( $post->ID ) )`. That should do the trick.

Comment: well done +1 ..